# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in Python

Tags: python, typeerror

Im making a function for my flappy bird clone that takes the `Pipe` class and the `PipeInvert`
class, and from the `possibleLevels` list selects one of 2 level Y numbers where the first one gets asigned to the normal pipe and the second one to the inverted pipe. But when running in keep getting this `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable` in `line 59`. Im using pygame.

Code so far:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

screen_width = 864
screen_height = 936

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Flappy Bird')




#load images
bg = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\Flappy Bird\img\bg.png')
ground_img = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\Flappy Bird\img\ground.png')
pipeImage = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\Flappy Bird\img\pipe.png')
pipeImageInv = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\code\Flappy Bird\img\pipeinv.png')


#Classes 
class Pipe():
    def __init__(self, img, x , y, pipe_scroll, scroll_speed):
        self.img = pipeImage
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pipe_scroll = pipe_scroll
        self.scroll_speed = scroll_speed
        
    def move(self):
        
        screen.blit(self.img, (self.pipe_scroll, y))
        self.pipe_scroll -= self.scroll_speed
        if self.pipe_scroll < -77:
            self.pipe_scroll = 864
            
class PipeInverted():
    def __init__(self, img, x , y, pipe_scroll, scroll_speed):
        self.img = pipeImageInv
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.pipe_scroll = pipe_scroll
        self.scroll_speed = scroll_speed
        
    def moveinvert(self):      
        screen.blit(self.img, (self.pipe_scroll, y))
        self.pipe_scroll -= self.scroll_speed
        if self.pipe_scroll < -77:
            self.pipe_scroll = 864

def levelSpawn():
    posLevels = [[220,-50], [250, -80]]
    select = randint(1,2)
    newNormal = Pipe(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[select[1]])
    newInvert = Pipe(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[select[2]])
    newNormal.move()
    newInvert.moveinvert()
        
        
        
#define game variables
ground_scroll = 0
pipe_scroll = 720
scroll_speed = 4

pipaKanonikh = Pipe(pipeImage, 5, 6, pipe_scroll, scroll_speed)
pipaAnapodh = PipeInverted(pipeImageInv, 5, 5, pipe_scroll, scroll_speed)

run = True
while run:

    clock.tick(fps)
    
    
    #draw background
    screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
    
    #draw and scroll pipe 
    levelSpawn()

    #draw and scroll the ground
    screen.blit(ground_img, (ground_scroll, 768))
    ground_scroll -= scroll_speed
    if abs(ground_scroll) > 0:
        ground_scroll = 0


    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: where is line 59 point it out for visual assistence

Comment: At line 58, after  `select = randint(1,2)`  the variable select contains an integer. Then, at line 59 you have select[1] end that is not possible with an integer because it is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 1):

On lines 59 and 60 you are trying to select the first value of `select` which is of type `integer` (and not a `list` or another subscriptable type).

Another problem you might encounter is an `IndexError` (first index of a `list` is `0` in python)

Depending on what you want to do you have two ways of fixing this error:

The following would  probably work:

```
newNormal = Pipe(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[select][0]) 
newInvert = PipeInverted(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[select][1]) 

# OR

newNormal = Pipe(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[0][select]) 
newInvert = PipeInverted(pipeImage, 5, posLevels[1][select])
```

(I changed the type of `newInvert` into `PipeInverted` because the class `Pipe` doesn't have a `moveInvert` method)

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `select` to a string or a list first

```
select = str(randint(1,2))
```